# Why is asp.net email timing out on host/server but not "local" remote using Visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses

This is a website asp.net c# application/form that allows a user to fill out an online form.  When form completed an email is sent.

When application is run on Visual Studio, works great.   But on host/server we get intermittent timeout so roughly 9 out of 10 times the email send function will fail.

We are hosting the application on Arvixe and using AmazonSes as our stmp email server (since 2018)

Background:

- The error is: **System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The operation has timed out** which occurs only when application is run on the hosted server.  Runs fine in local Visual studio.
- Timeout issues started around 8/13/21.
- Our asp.net/c# application code has not changed for months.
- Arvixe hosting environment has not changed (but they are still checking).  It is a windows server/machine.  We do not have admin rights to Arvixe server so we are relying on support through chat/email to do testing.
- AmazonSES email server environment and requirements have not changed.  A few days this started, an article suggested it could be outdated credentials.  We created new credentials, updating from sigV2 to sigV4, but still not working.

Possible reasons for the intermittent timeout:

- Arvixe firewall is blocking one of the AmazonSES IPs
- Connection is unstable between Arvixe/AmasonSES
- SMTP connection (made in app) remains open even after we dispose of it

Does anyone know why this would work in visual studio "local" but not on Arvixe server?   Any suggestions on what to do to isolate and resolve would be very welcomed.

Thank you.

---

Update:

- Arvixe can perform a Telent to AmazonSES showing connecting using port 587 and AmazonSES machine.
- Arvixe is using TLS 1.2
- The SSL using an older cypher, but not clear that is .

---

[image]

Webconfig

```
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="123@123.net">
    <network host="email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com" password="sssssss" port="587" userName="uuuu" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
```

Code that sends email

```
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    message.Sender = new MailAddress("to@email.net");
    message.From = new MailAddress("from@email.net");
    message.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("from@email.net"));

    Array arrToArray;
    char[] splitter = { ';' };

    arrToArray = SendToList.Split(splitter);

    foreach (string s in arrToArray)
    {
        if (s.Length > 2)
            message.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(s));
    }

    message.Subject = "Test 1 ";
    message.Body = "This is an email test";

    AlternateView textMail = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(message.Body, null, "text/plain");
    AlternateView htmlMail = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(message.Body, null, "text/html");

    LinkedResource header = new LinkedResource(AppPath + "logo.png");

    header.ContentId = "headerlog";
    htmlMail.LinkedResources.Add(header);

    message.AlternateViews.Add(textMail);
    message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlMail);

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Timeout = 20000;   // if removed, problem still occurs
    client.Send(message);
    client.Dispose();
```

Comment: Maybe your network admin changed the firewall settings for smtp and blocked port 587. Try 'telnet smtp.gmail.com 587' in your server console (telnet client has to be enabled in Windows, see https://www.technipages.com/windows-10-enable-telnet)

Comment: Good suggestion.   The server is hosted/shared account, dedicated IP.   Tried code with port 465 on host/server and local - both did not work.   Port 587 is recommended.

Comment: Any debug tool recommendations?   Opensocket, SMTP sniffer?  Need a simple asp.net c# debug solutions to ID our root cause fast.   Thanks